# Divide Line Into Sections Using Points Offset from It in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, linear-referencing, splitting

I have track (line) and milemarkers (point). Each point is offset by a different distance. Is there a way to find where each point would intersect the line if going perpendicularly out from the line?

As an analogy, imagine riding a train, sitting perpendicular to the direction of travel, looking out the window. Each time you see a milepost directly in front of you, you make note of your position on the track.

Comment: Are you looking for the algorithm to do this yourself, or are you wanting a push-button solution?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Snap Tool in the edit toolbox.  It looks like it does exactly what you are looking for.

[image: Snap Before and After]

Note that it requires at least an ArcEditor license.  For details on the tool see ESRI's help page on this tool.  [Snap Tool Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000007000000.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Near (Analysis)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000) (I linked to the 10.0 documentation, since you didn't specify your version).

If you choose the `location` option, the tool will edit the intersect positions into the milemarkers' table, into two new fields `NEAR_X` and `NEAR_Y`. If you want to create a new feature class using these coordinates, I don't know if there's a tool for that, but if you can handle python, you can definitely do it there. Again, I don't know which version you have, but for 10.0 (with arcpy) this should work:

```py
import arcpy

# first parameter; the geodatabase where to store the new feature class
db = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
# second parameter; the feature class with the mile markers
milemarkers_layername = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
# third parameter; the name of the feature class to create
intersects_layername = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(2)

# create the new feature class
arcpy.CreateFeatureClass_management(db, intersects_layername, 'POINT')

# create the cursors
mCur = arcpy.SearchCursor(milemarkers_layername)
iCur = arcpy.InsertCursor(db + '/' + intersects_layername)

for mRow in mCur:
  iRow = iCur.newRow()
  # read the values given by the Near tool
  near_x = mRow.getValue('NEAR_X')
  near_y = mRow.getValue('NEAR_Y')
  # create a new point with those values, then add it to the new table
  iPoint = arcpy.Point(near_x, near_y)
  iRow.shape = iPoint
  iCur.insertRow(iRow)

# free up both layers
del mRow, mCur, iRow, iCur
```

I'm not at work right now, so I can't test that (the catch-22 being that when I *am* at work, I have to be doing other things than hanging around SO), but I did my best to check it for errors. Hopefully someone can verify it for me.

Near (Analysis) requires an ArcInfo license.

Edit: by the way, don't set the search radius too high, or the search might take *ages* (depending on the amount of data you have).

Comment: If you want to go this route, the tool to create a point feature class from the coordinates is the Make XY Event Layer.  You'll want to export the nearX and nearY fields from the original feature into a table first.

Answer (score 1):

How about an out-of-the-box tool "Split Line at Point"? You can find it in Data Management Toolbox, Features Toolset. From the online help - Splits line features based on intersection or proximity to point features. Accepts a search radius. License level - ArcInfo or Advanced.